# Run a program when USB mass storage device connected

Tags: windows-7, usb-flash-drive, usb-storage, event-log

I want to run a program, say a batch file, when any USB mass storage device is connected. I also want to pass the drive letter as a parameter to this batch file.

This can perhaps be achieved using combination of event manager and task scheduler but I don't know how.
I am also open to use third party programs as long as they are free.

I actually know a [software](http://safelyremove.com) that has this capability. But I am looking for a free alternative.

PS: I am running Windows 7 x64 Ultimate

Comment: some parts are common in both questions....but that question does not have a satisfactory answer...moreover, i need to pass the drive letter as a command line argument...

Comment: No satisfactory answer doesn't mean dupes are allowed. Also, if there's a solution for reliable detection via Event Logs, the logs should contain details about which drive letter was assigned. It should be obvious that people looking into this would want to do something *with* the drive (eg. copy files) when it's plugged in, for which the drive letter is a must. That bit's pretty much a given to go along with the main problem. Finally, while searching I found 3-4 more questions along the same line as yours and marked all as duplicates, so pretty sure there's an exact dupe somewhere among them.

Comment: Also see [here](http://www.pcguide.com/vb/showthread.php?70158-Automatically-run-a-batch-file-on-USB-device-insertion-removal). It just occurred to me - instead of passing the drive letter to the batch file, the batch file itself can figure out which removable drives are connected once it is invoked. `wmic logicaldisk where drivetype=2` will show all attributes, else filter like this: `wmic logicaldisk where drivetype=2 get caption,description,drivetype,filesystem,volumename`. devcon can also help; use `devcon find *usbstor*` or `devcon status *usbstor*`.

Comment: @Karan although I agree that in this case there are several relevant pre-existing questions, keep in mind that [a moderate degree of duplication is not inherently a bad thing](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/). In this particular case, I do think it's a pretty exact duplicate, and an answer on the older question would meet the needs of the newer question.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite easy using EventVwr - just right click on the event and click "Attach task to this event".
You just need to find the specific event you want.
When I plugged an USB mass storage device it triggered the following events (under application category):
20001, 20003, 7036 and a few other less relevant.
You just need to test those events against other USB devices events to avoid false positives.

Comment: ok..any possibility of sending drive letter as a parameter?..PS: there is event 2006 as well i guess

Comment: Couldn't find anything about drive letter in those events.
You can use Karan script (which is pretty smart) and modify it to your needs.
But, I know there is a way to connect to any drive and folder with junctions.
I've used it in the past to enter specific shadow volume copy, so I suppose it can be used here as well.
For that you'll need to get the UNC of the USB drive, and create a Junction to it.